# Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many

Tags: django, many-to-many

I am trying to assign value to a ManyToManyField, however, any attempt I make to set a value on the db fails.

Below is my simplified models.py

```
class AppointmentRequest(models.Model):
    my_name = models.TextField(default='')
    requester_name = models.TextField(default='')
    meeting_date = models.TextField(default='')


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    firstname = models.TextField(default='')
    appointments = models.ManyToManyField(AppointmentRequest)
```

Below is the function in views.py that handles some functionality:

```
from .models import AppointmentRequest

def book_appointment(request, template_name)
    apt_request = AppointmentRequest()
    apt_request.requester_name = requesting_user
    apt_request.meeting_date = date
    apt_request.save()
    update_user.appointments = apt_request
    update_user.save()
```

With the above I get the following error `Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use appointments.set() instead.`

However, if I use `set` instead of `=`, I get the following error `django manytomany 'str' object has no attribute 'set'`. I am not sure what the problem is. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code is not clear what `update_user` is, but it's probably not an instance of `CustomUser`.

As mentioned by the error, you can't use direct assignment to add elements to a M2M, you must use `add` or `set` (more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Check the type of `update_user`, check where it comes from, are you sure it's your `CustomUser` instance? The name reminds of a function.

Maybe the user you are looking for is `request.user`, the user making the request, if that is the case your code would be:

```py
def book_appointment(request, template_name)
    apt_request = AppointmentRequest()
    apt_request.requester_name = requesting_user
    apt_request.meeting_date = date
    apt_request.save()
    request.user.appointments.add(apt_request)
```

Note that you don't need to save the model instance when you use M2M fields.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to add that line. update_user is defined as `update_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username)`. So, I think this agrees with what you mention above. I changed the last line as follows: `update_user.appointments.add(apt_request)`. This seems to run without the previous error. However, when I try to access this user object in another view, it seems to return an empty object. I also tried with `update_user.save()` and that did not help either. The other view tries to do the following. `update_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username)` and print its value.

Comment: When I try to access this object again within the same function, it returns an empty object too. Here is what I tried to do within the same function `update_user1 = CustomUser.objects.get(username); print(update_user1.appointments)`. The returned value is `users.AppointmentRequest.None`.

Comment: The call actually works, and it returned a queryset that one has to loop over to obtain the results.